# How to declare a image pointer in python ctypes?

Tags: c, python-3.x, ctypes

I have a function in Fingerprint which Scans a fingerprint input on the sensor and retrieves the image of it. The function name and parameter description are as below:

```
UF_ScanImage( UFImage* image )
```

Parameters

image -  
Pointer to the `UFImage` structure.

Can you please help me out on how to declare image in python `ctypes`.

Also can you please explain me this -

```
UFImage* image = (UFImage*)malloc( UF_IMAGE_HEADER_SIZE +
UF_MAX_IMAGE_SIZE );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `c_void_p` as the type:

```
dll.UF_ScanImage.argtypes = c_void_p,
img = create_string_buffer(UF_IMAGE_HEADER_SIZE + UF_MAX_IMAGE_SIZE)
```

Or for exact type checking you can create a (possibly empty) Structure definition and cast the allocation to a pointer:

```
class UFImage(Structure): pass
dll.UF_ScanImage.argtypes = POINTER(UFImage),
img = cast(create_string_buffer(UF_IMAGE_HEADER_SIZE + UF_MAX_IMAGE_SIZE),POINTER(UFImage))
```